# find out which link was clicked in its onClickTopics

Tags: jquery, struts2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.subscribe('linkclicked',function(){
          //code to find out the id of which sj:a was clicked
      }); </script>

<sj:a id="link1" href="n1.action" targets="maindiv" onClickTopics="linkclicked">Link1</sj:a>
<sj:a id="link2" href="n2.action" targets="maindiv" onClickTopics="linkclicked">Link2</sj:a>
<sj:a id="link2" href="n3.action" targets="maindiv" onClickTopics="linkclicked">Link3</sj:a>
```

What code should be written to find out the id of the link which is clicked?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `event` object which is the first argument in the handler to find the target element which triggered the event. Try this.

```
$.subscribe('linkclicked',function(event){
      //code to find out the id of which sj:a was clicked
      alert(event.target.id);
});
```

Comment: Can you check in console `console.log(event)`?

Comment: lets continue in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7405/struts2-jquery-plugin